# Installing gcc twice on a Snow Leopard machine?

Tags: command-line, snow-leopard

I have an old early 2008 Macbook that runs Snow Leopard and can't upgrade to anything better. I wanted to install a C++ compiler on it and finally stumbled across this:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

I did something pretty stupid. I ran the install twice...

What effects would this have? Will it take up two times the space on my computer? The compiler itself seems to be working fine in the command line, but I'd like to get rid of any useless files from installing it twice. If so, how can I do that?

Comment: I’m sure you can upgrade the MacBook to something newer than Snow Leopard if it’s 2008 ... as an FYI, at the very least Lion or Mountain Lion

Comment: There is an old version of Homebrew for Snow Leopard - just install that and then brew install gcc

Comment: Macports keeps builds up to date for p;d Systems - there are updates for Tiger onwards - the earlier ones will miss sonme ports mainly where the source uses new features

Comment: Where does the installer write to? I would expect it to be by default to the same files every time.